# Git push default to github

Tags: git, github

Right now if I type `git push -u origin master` it will push my repository to github. Is there a way to achieve the same effect but only having to type `git push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By typing `git config --global push.default simple` in git bash I was able to achieve the desired effect. Now every time I type `git push` it automatically pushes to github.

Comment: By doing this, it will default to the 'origin' remote. This doesn't just apply to Github

Answer (score 1):

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the  argument, branch.*.remote configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to origin.

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

So the answer is: yes, that's possible. It will default to *origin*